# Why was the tag thingie removed? Please bring it back!

Tags: support, feature-request, user-interface

### Edit (Feb. 25th, 2014):

The meta.SO link in Jeremy's answer has been updated to say that the tag thingie is **not coming back**.

Therefore I officially change this to a feature request.

> Is it possible to bring back the functionality of the "tag thingie" and have an accessible place on the page (even as a tooltip, although that is less favorable), where we can see how many questions are tagged with each of the used tags?

---

When opening a question, there used to be on the right part of the screen, a list of the used tags and their sizes. You can still see this on meta, but not on the main site.

I found this information to be incredibly helpful for several reasons:

1. It allowed me to see if a new tag was created.
2. It allowed me to see if the current tags are all popular, and to decide whether or not a retag is needed.

   For example, asking a question about ordered fields and using just the [ordered-fields](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ordered-fields) tag is probably gonna reduce the exposure of the question, and [field-theory](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/field-theory) might be a reasonable addition; on the other hand [group-theory](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/group-theory) won't be needing [abstract-algebra](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/abstract-algebra) to increase the exposure of the question.

> **Please bring it back!**

---

### Possibly a bug?

It seems to show up on Chromium. But not on Firefox (27.0, Arch Linux 64bit; confirmed by robjohn in the comments 26.0, Mac). This is across the entire SE network, the "tagged" element shows up on meta sites but not on main sites.

Comment: You mean [this](http://i.stack.imgur.com/gh44O.png)?

Comment: @ArthurFischer: I don't see that at the top of my main question pages.

Comment: @Arthur: Yes. That thing.

Comment: @rob: Good thing that I'm not alone here. What browser are you using?

Comment: @AsafKaragila: Firefox 26.0 for Mac

Comment: @robjohn: Okay then, it's not a bug from updating FF to 27.0. :-)

Comment: @Arthur: Inspecting the HTML elements shows that this doesn't even appear on the code of the main site.

Comment: I'm seeing the tags on Chrome (32.0.1700.107 m for Win7) but not Firefox (26.0 for Win7). ....and after updating Firefox to 27.0 I'm seeing the tags there, too.

Comment: @robjohn: But seems a bug nonetheless!

Comment: @AsafKaragila: I don't know if this is the problem, but I see this in the page source: `"question_show_tweaks":{"v":"sidebar_wo_tag_stats","g":2}`

Comment: @AsafKaragila: the mods were discussing in chat that some saw `"question_show_tweaks":{"v":"sidebar_wo_tag_stats","g":1}` and we figured there might be some testing with two random groups.

Answer (score 8):

This is currently being discussed over on MSO:

[Tags are not showing up on the right side of the screen](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/219767/tags-are-not-showing-up-on-the-right-side-of-the-screen)

Basically, we're just testing.

Comment: Thank you for letting me know.

Comment: Are you done testing?

Comment: Not yet... Maybe Monday or Tuesday

Comment: Because it's back now.

Comment: It's split on IP plus user agent...you upgrade your browser?

Comment: Not since last night. My IP has changed, though. (But this was also true on my Windows 8 tablet from two other IP addresses today on FF 26.)

Comment: Well, keep in mind, every time one of those things changes you've got a 50% chance of being in a new group

Comment: Hm. I see. Interesting way of testing.

Comment: Best we can do, because we need some method that can be calculated on the spot.  We don't have the capability to mark someone and track them throughout the system. IP plus user agent hash can be computed anytime we need it

Comment: Well, you can also troll the users. Make the computing non-deterministic, and save the result for two hours so for two hours the user will experience the same test group across the servers; but after two hours recalculate it.

Comment: @Asaf, don't give them any ideas!

Comment: It's Thursday now (Wednesday if you want to be pedantic), shouldn't it be back to normal by now?

Comment: It's been like... three weeks now. What's up with that?

Comment: @AsafKaragila We ended the experiment today, and I'm afraid we're not going to bring it back. Instead we are going to try to make the other group of tags more prominent and accessible.  Also discussed here: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/222820/202998

Comment: Yeah, I just noticed that and edited the main thread to a feature request. :-)

Comment: And for what it's worth, I feel that MSE often suffers a decrease in quality from its exposure on the hot questions list. So maybe it's not that great of idea after all? :-)

Comment: @AsafKaragila I'm sympathetic to the argument, but unfortunately we don't have any good way to measure "quality" with our split testing system. I might argue that while you might get some less than wonderful users, there is also a chance that someone who can really contribute will be drawn to the site from somewhere else. At the moment, we are erring on the side of bringing more exposure to our smaller sites.